# Speed up game ROMs with RetroPie

Tags: retropie, processor-speed

Apart from overclocking my Pi (already done), is it possible to speed up and emulated game as some ROMs that I play, (specifically Final Fantasy 6 for the SNES) as the music in the game drops at the end of each note and sounds off so it's quite annoying to play. I've tested the same ROM file on my laptop and the sound issue doesn't happen so I know it's not a problem with the ROM itself.

Most games run just fine but I was wondering if there were any more little tips to help speed up the ROMs?

Answer (score 1):

During the startup of your rom, have keyboard attached and press the X key.
Navigate the menu and try another emulator. Some emulators work better then others for specific games.

You don't have the change the default value, you can specify it just for this rom. Normally, these settings should be saved for the next run.

If all emulators have the same issue and they are all updated, check the list of experimental emulators and try to install a new one if there is one listed. (pref. binary install)

Answer (score 0):

Press space to speed games up in RetroPie: I believe it doubles game and music speed. Press it again to undo. E also slows it down.

If you are using a controller, you can configure buttons if there are spare ones not used for the console you are using. A-Z of RetroPie has a nice tutorial for this. Otherwise, you will need a keyboard.

Overclocking will increase your framerate, not gamespeed. If that's what you want, try changing your GPU/CPU split in raspiconfig. Otherwise, aside from upgrading to a B+ or creating a cluster, nothing can be done.

I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

@Kieran mentioned "space" bar and "B+", neither of which I think will help with your sound problem.
Please provide evidence the CPU speed is the cause of your sound problem or edit your question to say it's only your assumption. if CPU speed is the issue underclocking should make it worse and upgrading to a rpi2b may help if the emulator is multi-threaded. But I seem to recall there is a setting for sound fixes. Try editing /etc/retroarch.cfg  https://github.com/petrockblog/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Sound-Issues